# How to get rid of error on Phonegap generated app?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

As i am new to Phonegap. I have downloaded code from.. https://github.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile for moodle.
After downloading i tried to run app from Phonegap website. I have uploaded code but after successful build i cant get desired output.

How to get out of this issue. 
I am totally new to Phonegap. Have watched documents and videos but still cant get desired output.
Also suggest me if my way to generate Application is wrong.
[image: I got error as shown in Image while i open app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried all things.
After looking out other things i came to know that there was issue with my language files also i was using zip file to get apk. But linking Phonegap with Github solved my problem.